# getting exception while running selenium test in maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am using java,maven,selenium-webdriver.I have added dependencies '**selenium-server 2.32.0','selenium-java 2.32.0**'.But I am getting Exception as follows:
Here is the code:-

```
public class ABC{
   private static WebDriver webDriver ;
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
        .usingDriverExecutable(
                new File("/root/Downloads/chromedriver"))
                .usingAnyFreePort().build();
        service.start();
        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),
                DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
          //webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    }
}
```

As you see,I also created firefoxdriver instance but getting same exception.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129).
```

Also added '**httpclient 4.1.2**'.But getting same exception,please guide me how to solve this

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace and code?

Comment: There is a template here you could try:  https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Answer (score 0):

Use correct structure below example of service usage(And then just extends Settings inside your class with tests)

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Settings {
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    protected static String baseURL = "base url for tests";
    public static ChromeDriverService service;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void createAndStartService() {
        service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("pass to your browser")).usingAnyFreePort()
                 .build();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void createAndStopService() {
        service.stop();
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }
   }
```